# Passing down a given int to other methods

Tags: java

I have been working with the Learning with robots package for a uni assignment and I have hit a snag. I have created a class called DeliveryBot and in order for it to work the int 'size' needs to be used in other methods.

```
import becker.robots.*;

public class DistributeBot extends RobotSE
{
//constructor
public DistributeBot(City aCity, int aStreet, int anAvenue, Direction aDirection, int      numThings) 
    { 
        super(aCity, aStreet, anAvenue, aDirection, numThings); 
    }

//Methods must include one called putThings which has a parameter to define the size  of the squares.
    public void putThings(int size)
    {
        this.setSquare();
        this.positionRobot();
        this.setSquare();
    }

    private void setSquare()
    {
        for(int numRows = 0; numRows <= size; numRows++)
        {
            this.setRow();
        }
    }

    private void setRow()
    {
        for(int numColumns = 0; numColumns <= size; numColumns++)
        {
            this.putThing();
            this.move();
        }
        this.faceSouth();
        this.move();
    }

    private void turnToFaceNextRow()
    {       
        if(size & 1) == 0)
        {
            this.turnRight();
        }
    else
        {
            this.turnLeft();
        }
    }

    private void faceSouth()
    {
        while(this.getDirection() != Direction.SOUTH)
        {
            this.turnRight();
        }
    }

    private void positionRobot()
    {
        if(this.getDirection() == Direction.WEST)
        {
        this.move(size);
        this.move();
        this.turnLeft();
        this.move();
        this.turnLeft();
        }
        else
        {
        this.turnAround();
        this.move();
        this.turnLeft();
        this.move();
        this.turnLeft();
        }
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the other uses of the int 'size', used in the putThings(int size) method, come up with a 'missing symbol' error, telling me that the 'size' stated in other methods such as:

```
private void setSquare()
{
    for(int numRows = 0; numRows <= size; numRows++)
    {
        this.setRow();
    }
}
```

is not recognised as the same 'size'. The idea is that the whole task can be carried out with one line of code:

```
karel.putThings(4);
```

with 4, ie. int size, defining the dimensions of 'squares'.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you call the other methods, you need to set `size` to a class variable, preferably `private`, that the other methods in your class can access. You are not setting `size` anywhere so it is just lost. Another option is to pass `size` into the methods you call.

Comment: For one thing, the variable `size` isn't used by the constructor it is passed to. Even after the method call, the value of that variable will be unknown to all classes _except_ the class that made the call to `putThings(int size)`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. @mdewitt I would like to pass on 'size' into my methods.

Comment: So set the int as a private variable in the class

Comment: Okay just change the method signatures for `setSquare` and `positionRobot` to take an `int` and you can pass in `size` and use it in each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing the assignment specifications but it seems to me that you really want the `putThings()` functionality to be a part of the constructor.

What you need to do is declare `private int size;` at the very beginning of the entire class (before the constructor). You declare it with no value just so that the compiler knows that this object (the DistributeBot) will have an attribute called `size` that is a `private int` .

You can declare your attributes as `public`, `default`, `private`, or `protected`. In most cases, you should set your attributes to private so you can't accidentally tinker with them outside of the class in which the object was created. Default would just be `int size;`

In order to modify a private variable, you create getters and setters conventionally named getVariable() and setVariable(type var) where getVariable returns a variable of whatever type the variable being retrieved is and setVariable is a void function that sets the variable. This privacy 'encapsulates' the attributes (or the methods, like you have done already) in a class so that, like I mentioned earlier, no one can call them from outside of the class in which the object was created.

So in between the constructor and the beginning of the class you will put `private int size;` and then in your constructor you should change the paramaters to add (int size) to it.

```
public class DistributeBot extends RobotSE
{
    private int size;

    //note that although you can't see it unless you scroll to the right
    //the constructor now has 'int size' as the last parameter
    public DistributeBot(City aCity, int aStreet, int anAvenue, Direction aDirection, int numThings, int size) 
    { 
        super(aCity, aStreet, anAvenue, aDirection, numThings); 

        //you technically DON'T have to do this next line if you 
        //don't create the attribute 'size' for this class but you 
        //probably should. It's hard to tell from your description.

        this.setSize(size); 

        //notice how below I use 'this.size' because this 
        //object officially has an attribute called size

        this.putThings(this.size);

        ...

        //anything else you want to do in the constructor 
        //you can put the functionality of putThings in here if you want
    }

   ...

    private int getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }
    private void setSize(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat, sorry for the lack of coherent formatting or description. My assignment questions are very vague and have been giving me a headache. Thanks Matthew, and all who commented.